# Under certain conditions, prove: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$. Furthermore let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n = \infty$ and a sequence such that there exists a $C > 0$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n$|$≤C$ for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n) = 0$$

So what I basically know is that I have this sequence $x_n$ with the property that the difference of all subsequent terms of the sequence are bounded by a real number $C$. Also, I know that $f'(x) = 0$ or almost $0$ for large enough $x$. Combining both conditions it also means that if I look at $f(x_n)$ then the difference on the domain of two subsequent terms is bounded and since I know that the slope is almost $0$ I can also tell that the difference between the functional value of two subsequent terms is $0$ for $x\to\infty$.

I think this is the general idea of the proof, but I don't know how to begin the proof itself.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mean value theorem, $$f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)=f'(\xi_n)(x_{n+1} -  x_n ),\quad \xi_n\in[x_n,x_{n+1}].$$
The first factor goes to zero and the second one is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem to show $|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)| \le |f'(\xi_n)| |x_{n+1}-x_n|$ for some $\xi_n \in [x_n, x_{n+1} ]$. Then combine $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \le C$ and the fact that $f^{\prime}(\xi_n) \to 0$ to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$, let $M > 0$ such that $\left|f'(x)\right| < \epsilon$ for $x > M$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$, let $N > 0$ such that $x_n > M$ for all $n > N$.

Now, by the mean value theorem, for all $n > N$, we have:

$$\left|f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)\right| = \left|(x_{n+1} - x_n)f'(\zeta_n)\right| \le C \epsilon$$

for some $\zeta_n \in [x_n, x_{n+1}]$. Thus $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left|f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)\right| = 0$ as desired.